# Returning Column valuses and Sum() of column valuses in one MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table:

```
id, cust#, payment, date
1, cus1, 508, 2010-01-01
2, cus2, 40, 2010-01-01
3, cus1, 13, 2010-01-02
```

I have this for my query.

```
select id, cust#, payment, date group by cust#
```

As expected it returns the results. I need it to return each column value plus a value for the `sum(payment) as totalpayments`

I can't figure it out as this only will return total for payments and not each payment amount plus the total

```
select id, cust#, sum(payment), date group by cust#
```

This is what i want in a sense even though this is not a valid query

```
select id, cust#, payment, sum(payment) AS totalpayments, date group by cust#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a sub-query:

```
select
    id,
    cust#,
    (select 
        sum(payment) 
    from 
        mytable 
    group by 
        cust#
    ) as totalpayments, 
    date 
from
    mytable
```